# Redirect user from login page based on the option they selected

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have an application in Laravel where I have a common login page. From this login page users will have an option to get redirected to the Admin page or App page.

How do I implement this??

Do I have to make a new login page for the admin redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign roles to your users and then on login check the role. And on the base of role redirect them to whatever page you want. [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) is great plugin which really helps in role management.

After authenticating the user

```
if ($user->roles()->first() == 'Admin')
    //redirect to your Admin page
else
    //redirect to app page
```

There are multiple ways to redirect. [Read docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects)

Comment: I am using Entrust. But, how do I redirect them based on their roles?

Comment: Where you are authenticating the user at login and you have confirmed that its a valid user of your system. Now write an If condition in which check the role of user `if $user->role == 'Admin'` redirect it to Admin page `else` redirect to App page.